# Getting entity from form with data_class - the correct way in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

If I have a FormType Object with setDefaultOptions method that sets a data_class, how should I get the entity from it for persisting in Doctrine ORM?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CarModelsType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist(????HERE????);
        }
```

Should I put $form->getData() in "????HERE????". I'm just not sure if it's the correct way since it looks nasty

Answer (score 1):

For a createAction():

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new CarModel();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CarModelTypeType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        //...
    }
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases.

**1) You gave an object to your form :**

The object is automatically updated and hydrated with new values from the form, you can save the object.

```
$carModel = ... ; // Get or new object of the entity

$form = $this->createForm(new CarModelsType(), $carModel); // Note, $carModel is given
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($carModel); // Save the object $carModel
    $em->flush();
}
```

**2) You don't give an object when intitializing your form :**

So you need to retrieve the entity with `$form->getData()`.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CarModelsType()); // Note : no object given
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($form->getData()); // You get the object after with $form->getData()
    $em->flush();
}
```

**In addition :**

Note that `$form->getData()` works always, even when you give an object to your form ! So, you can use `$form->getData()` all the time !

Comment: btw number 1 is just useless because as I said, I specify the data_class in the form class

Comment: No, it's not the same thing at all ! Giving an object allow you to edit an existing object, or to give default value to the form while 'data_class' is used to validate !

Comment: Isn't specifying data_class just like giving the createForm an empty entity?